# alternate of indexof in javascript to find items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have set of paths in a array .So some path are **constants** and some paths are **dynamic** .

**constant** path mean Example `"/booking-success"`
**Dynamic** path mean Example `'/arrival/view/:job_order_number'` --> here job_order_number is dynamice. so `/arrival/view/123 , /arrival/view/456`.

I need to check whether url present or not .I am trying like this

```
const children = [
'/booking-success',
'/back-request',
'/arrival/view/:job_order_number'
]
let path = "/booking-success";
// outout true ----> correct
console.log(children.indexOf(path) !=-1)


let path1 = "/arrival/view/1233";

// outout false ----> wrong
// expected true
console.log(children.indexOf(path1) !=-1)
```

I am not getting expected output.**expected output is true** which method I can you ?

Comment: Have a look at [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), the "I need to find things based on some property" versions of indexOf. (And probably give the list of Array functions a renewed look, there's a _lot_ of useful functions in there far too many people don't know about, like `some`, `flat`, `unshift`, etc.)

Comment: which method is best in this senario

Comment: which method is suitable to get true of false whether url present or not

Comment: Doesn't matter: JS is not strictly typed. `find` will return the first matched object, or `undefined` if there are no matches, `findIndex` does the same as `indexOf`, where it returns a number `0` or higher as the array position of the first match in the array, or `-1` if nothing matches. You don't need "true" or "false", just write your conditional to `!== undefined`, or `!== -1`, based on whether you use `find` or `findIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for this, comparing paths by splitting them on `/` and comparing each individual element and the overall length of the path, allowing path elements which start with `:` to match anything:

```js
const children = [
  '/booking-success',
  '/back-request',
  '/arrival/view/:job_order_number'
]

const findChild = (path) => children
  .findIndex((child, _, arr) => {
    childParts = child.split('/')
    pathParts = path.split('/')
    return childParts.every((v, i) => v[0] == ':' || v == pathParts[i]) &&
      childParts.length == pathParts.length
  }) !== -1

paths = [
 "/booking-success",
 "/arrival/view/1233",
 "/arrival/jobs/1233",
 "/booking-success/1234",
 "/departure/view/1233",
 "/arrival/view",
 "/back-request"
]

paths.forEach(p => console.log(`${p} : ${findChild(p)}`))
```